# Maximize - Non binding constraint is changing the result

Tags: constraint, maximum

When I add a non-binding constraint to a maximization problem the result changes. I don't understand why.

Below you can find the code that I am using.

For the maximization A, H = 6837.66
For the maximization B (equal to A + constraint of H less or equal to 14000), H = 5716.08

If the solution in A is already below 14000, the solution should not change. Why is this happening?

Thank you!

````
$Assumptions -> {{β, θ, α, r, p, ϵ, σ, δ} > 0, Element [{H, β, θ, α, r, p, ϵ, σ, δ}, Reals], {β, θ, α, r, p, ϵ, σ, δ} < 1, H > 0, ϵ > σ, α < r};

Y = 1000;
β = 0.95;
θ = 10;
α = 0.05;
r = 0.05;
ϵ = 1.2;
σ = 0.2;
δ = 0.3;
p = 0.51;

g1[H_] := Max[0, ((((1 - δ)*Y)/(r + α)) - H)]*((((1 - δ)*Y)/(r + α)) - H)^(-1)

h1[H_] :=  Min[0, ((((1 - δ)*Y)/(r + α)) - H)]*((((1 - δ)*Y)/(r + α)) - H)^(-1)

A = Maximize[{(1 + β * (1 - 
          p))*(((Y - r*H)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (θ*H)^(1 - 
             1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 
            1/ϵ))) /(1 - 1/σ) +  β*p *
     g1[H] *(((Y - (r + α)*H)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (θ*
             H)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 
            1/ϵ)) ) /(1 - 1/σ) + β*p *
     h1[H] *(((δ*Y)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (θ*5000)^(1 - 
             1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 
            1/ϵ)) ) /(1 - 1/σ), 
   H ⩾ 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0}, {H}]



B = Maximize[{(1 + β * (1 - 
          p))*(((Y - r*H)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (θ*H)^(1 - 
             1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 
            1/ϵ))) /(1 - 1/σ) +  β*p *
     g1[H] *(((Y - (r + α)*H)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (θ*
             H)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 
            1/ϵ)) ) /(1 - 1/σ) + β*p *
     h1[H] *(((δ*Y)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (θ*5000)^(1 - 
             1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 
            1/ϵ)) ) /(1 - 1/σ), 
   H ⩾ 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0, 
   H <= 14000}, {H}]

```
````

Comment: In principle it shouldn't change, but in practice constrained vs. unconstrained optimization are two very different problems. The algorithms used behind the scenes to solve them may also be very different, maybe using different choices of starting values, and possibly leading to different results. How different are your results in the two cases?

Comment: I need to simulate different solutions using different parameter values. When I create a vector for the solutions using option B the results stop making sense (as a vector).

I know that the option A is the correct one, but as I need to compute thousands of solutions, I need to trust the function. At this moment, I don't feel comfortable at all with Maximize.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the discontinuity in your function.  Your function has a division by zero when $H=\frac{(1-\delta ) Y}{\alpha +r}$.  For your particular set of parameters that happens when $H=7000$.  You might need to perform `Maximize` twice:  once with $H<\frac{(1-\delta ) Y}{\alpha +r}$ and another with $H>\frac{(1-\delta ) Y}{\alpha +r}$.  Then take the maximum of the two results.

Comment: And setting $H$ to something just less than $\frac{Y-\delta  Y}{\alpha +r}$ seems to be the maximum in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `RandomSearch` and the multiplication by `10^24` do the job.

```
Element[{H, \[Beta], \[Theta], \[Alpha], r, 
p, \[Epsilon], \[Sigma], \[Delta]},  Reals], {\[Beta], \[Theta], \[Alpha], r, 
p, \[Epsilon], \[Sigma], \[Delta]} < 1, H > 0, \[Epsilon] > \[Sigma], \[Alpha] < r};

Y = 1000;\[Beta] = 0.95;\[Theta] = 10;\[Alpha] = 0.05;r = 0.05;
\[Epsilon] = 1.2;\[Sigma] = 0.2;\[Delta] = 0.3;p = 0.51;
g1[H_] :=  Max[0, ((((1 - \[Delta])*Y)/(r + \[Alpha])) - 
 H)]*((((1 - \[Delta])*Y)/(r + \[Alpha])) - H)^(-1)
h1[H_] :=  Min[0, ((((1 - \[Delta])*Y)/(r + \[Alpha])) - 
 H)]*((((1 - \[Delta])*Y)/(r + \[Alpha])) - H)^(-1)

A = NMaximize[{10^24*((1 + \[Beta]*(1 - 
        p))*(((Y - r*H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*H)^(1 - 
           1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
          1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma]) + \[Beta]*p*
   g1[H]*(((Y - (r + \[Alpha])*H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*
           H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
          1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma]) + \[Beta]*p*
   h1[H]*(((\[Delta]*Y)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*5000)^(1 - 
           1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
          1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma])), 
   H \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, (Y - r*H) \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0}, {H}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 250}]
```

> `{-3.26868, {H -> 7000.}}`

```
B = NMaximize[{10^24*((1 + \[Beta]*(1 - 
        p))*(((Y - r*H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*H)^(1 - 
           1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
          1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma]) + \[Beta]*p*
   g1[H]*(((Y - (r + \[Alpha])*H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*
           H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
          1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma]) + \[Beta]*p*
   h1[H]*(((\[Delta]*Y)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*5000)^(1 - 
           1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
          1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma])), 
   H \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, (Y - r*H) \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, H <= 14000}, {H}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 250}]
```

> `{-3.26868, {H -> 7000.}}`

Comment: Taking `"SearchPoints" -> 1000` in the above, we obtain close (but not identical) results without  the multiplication by `10^24`,

Answer (score 0):

Let us build the plot

```
Plot[(1 + \[Beta]*(1 - 
    p))*(((Y - r*H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*H)^(1 - 
       1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 
  1/\[Sigma]) + \[Beta]*p*   g1[H]*(((Y - (r + \[Alpha])*H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*
       H)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 
      1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 1/\[Sigma]) + \[Beta]*p* h1[H]*(((\[Delta]*Y)^(1 - 1/\[Epsilon]) + (\[Theta]*5000)^(1 - 
       1/\[Epsilon]))^((1 - 1/\[Sigma])/(1 - 1/\[Epsilon])))/(1 - 
  1/\[Sigma]), {H, 5000, 7000}]
```

[image]

I think the question is closed.

Addition. See the plot on `{H,5000,15000}`
[image]

Comment: The plot confirms that the maximization in A is the correct one. The problem is that I need to trust the maximize function and I need to create a vector for the solutions with different parameters and the constraint in B.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your function is not continuous at $H= \frac{Y-\delta  Y}{\alpha +r}$ as at that value of $H$ there is a division by zero.

If $H\leq \frac{Y-\delta  Y}{\alpha +r}$, then `g1[H]=1` and `h1[H]=0`.  Otherwise, `g1[H]=1` and `h1[H]=0`. That gives two functions:

```
f1 = ((1 + (1 - p) β) ((-H r + Y)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (H θ)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/
  (1 - 1/σ) + (p β ((Y - H (r + α))^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (H θ)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/
  (1 - 1/σ)

f2 = (p β ((Y δ)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + 5000^(1 - 1/ϵ) θ^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/(1 - 1/σ) +
  ((1 + (1 - p) β) ((-H r + Y)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (H θ)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/(1 - 1/σ)
```

Maximize both functions (with the appropriate restrictions on $H$), and then take the maximum result:

```
Y = 1000;
β = 0.95;
θ = 10;
α = 0.05;
r = 0.05;
ϵ = 1.2;
σ = 0.2;
δ = 0.3;
p = 0.51;
sol1 = Maximize[{f1, H <= (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), H > 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0}, H]
(* {-3.26868*10^-24, {H -> 7000.}} *)
sol2 = Maximize[{f2, H > (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), H > 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0}, H]
(* {-4.45483*10^-24, {H -> 14852.5}} *)
max = If[sol1[[1]] > sol2[[1]], sol1, sol2]
(* {-3.26868*10^-24, {H -> 7000.}} *)
```

This approach seems more stable when additional restrictions are added:

```
sol1 = Maximize[{f1, H <= (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), H > 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0, H < 14000}, H]
(* {-3.26868*10^-24, {H -> 7000.}} *)
sol2 = Maximize[{f2, H > (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), H > 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0, H < 14000}, H]
(* {-4.46379*10^-24, {H -> 14000.}} *)
max = If[sol1[[1]] > sol2[[1]], sol1, sol2]
(* {-3.26868*10^-24, {H -> 7000.}} *)
```

As a check on varying parameter values consider some sort of a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 f1 = ((1 + (1 - p) β) ((-H r + Y)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (H θ)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/(1 - 1/σ) + (p β ((Y - H (r + α))^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (H θ)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/(1 - 1/σ);
 f2 = (p β ((Y δ)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + 5000^(1 - 1/ϵ) θ^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/(1 - 1/σ) + ((1 + (1 - p) β) ((-H r + Y)^(1 - 1/ϵ) + (H θ)^(1 - 1/ϵ))^((1 - 1/σ)/(1 - 1/ϵ)))/(1 - 1/σ);
 sol1 = Maximize[{f1, H <= (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), H > 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0}, H];
 sol2 = Maximize[{f2, H > (Y - Y δ)/(r + α),  H > 0, (Y - r*H) ⩾ 0}, H]; 
 max = If[sol1[[1]] > sol2[[1]], sol1, sol2];
 hmin = 0.8 H /. sol1[[2]];
 hmax = 1.2 H /. sol2[[2]];
 {ymin, ymax} = 
  MinMax[{f1 /. H -> hmin, f1 /. H -> (Y - Y δ)/(r + α),
     f2 /. H -> (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), f2 /. H -> hmax}];
 y0 = ymin - 0.95 (ymax - ymin);
 y1 = ymax + 1.05 (ymax - ymin);
 Show[Plot[f1, {H, hmin, (Y - Y δ)/(r + α)}, PlotRange -> {{hmin, hmax}, {y0, y1}}],
  Plot[f2, {H, (Y - Y δ)/(r + α), hmax}, PlotRange -> {{hmin, hmax}, {y0, y1}}],
  ListPlot[{{{H /. max[[2]], max[[1]]}}, {{H /. sol1[[2]], sol1[[1]]}},
    {{H /. sol2[[2]], sol2[[1]]}}}, PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[0.03], Red}, Blue, Blue}]],
 {{Y, 1000}, 1, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{α, 0.05}, 0.02, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 0.05}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{δ, 0.3}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{β, 0.95}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{θ, 10}, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ϵ, 1.2}, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{σ, 0.2}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, 0.51}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {Y, α, r, δ, β, θ, σ, p}]
```

[image: Maxima for both parts of the function]

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  But when I bugged you, it was because you said you had thousands of these to do and because so much time had passed, I assumed you had given up on this forum.  Someone else might still have a better and maybe more stable answer.